# Handling errors from Spring WebClient in another method

Tags: spring, spring-webclient

In a Spring Boot application, I'm using `WebClient` to invoke a POST request to a remote application. The method currently looks like this:

```java
// Class A
public void sendNotification(String notification) {
    final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .defaultHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
    webClient.post()
            .uri("http://localhost:9000/api")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(notification))
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(NotificationException::new))
            .toBodilessEntity()
            .block();
    log.info("Notification delivered successfully");
}

// Class B
public void someOtherMethod() {
    sendNotification("test");
}
```

The use case is: A method in another class calls `sendNotification` and should handle any error, i.e. any non 2xx status or if the request couldn't even be sent.

But I'm struggling with the concept of handling errors in the `WebClient`. As far as I understood, the following line would catch any HTTP status other than 2xx/3xx and then return a `Mono.error` with the `NotificationException` (a custom exception extending `Exception`).

`onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(NotificationException::new))`

But how could `someOtherMethod()` handle this error scenario? How could it process this `Mono.error`? Or how does it actually catch the `NotificationException` if `sendNotification` doesn't even throw it in the signature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, there are many ways to handle errors, it really depends on what you want to do in case of an error.

In your current setup, the solution is straightforward: **first, `NotificationException` should extend `RuntimeException`**, thus, in case of an HTTP error, `.block()` will throw a `NotificationException`. It is a good practice to add it in the signature of the method, accompanied with a Javadoc entry.
In another method, you just need to catch the exception and do what you want with it.

```java
/**
 * @param notification
 * @throws NotificationException in case of a HTTP error
 */
public void sendNotification(String notification) throws NotificationException {
    final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .defaultHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .build();
    webClient.post()
        .uri("http://localhost:9000/api")
        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(notification))
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(NotificationException::new))
        .toBodilessEntity()
        .block();
    log.info("Notification delivered successfully");
}

public void someOtherMethod() {
    try {
        sendNotification("test");
    } catch (NotificationException e) {
        // Treat exception
    }
}
```

In a more reactive style, you could return a `Mono` and use [`onErrorResume()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorResume-java.lang.Class-java.util.function.Function-).

```java
public Mono<Void> sendNotification(String notification) {
    final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .defaultHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .build();
    return webClient.post()
        .uri("http://localhost:9000/api")
        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(notification))
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(NotificationException::new))
        .bodyToMono(Void.class);
}

public void someOtherMethod() {
    sendNotification("test")
        .onErrorResume(NotificationException.class, ex -> {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
            return Mono.empty();
        })
        .doOnSuccess(unused -> log.info("Notification delivered successfully"))
        .block();
}
```

Comment: Are not both solutions non-reactive? we are using block() in both of them.

Comment: @MuhammadAbuBakr Well, that depends on the point of view. The key difference is that in the second case, the `sendNotification` method is non-blocking, which starts the path of reactive programming. _Moreover, I’m not talking about the underlying mechanics, just programming style: historic Java vs functional programming_.
In the second example, you could delete the block, return a `Mono` and you’d be non-blocking all the way, except at some point you still need to get the result (by blocking or making a non-blocking endpoint).

Answer (score 4):

Using imperative/blocking style you can surround it with a try-catch:

```java
try {
    webClient.post()
            .uri("http://localhost:9000/api")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(notification))
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(NotificationException::new))
            .toBodilessEntity()
            .block();
} catch(NotificationException e) {...}
```

A reactive solution would be to use the `onErrorResume` operator like this:

```java
    webClient.post()
            .uri("http://localhost:9000/api")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(notification))
            .retrieve()
            .onErrorResume(e -> someOtherMethod())
            .toBodilessEntity();
```

Here, the reactive method `someOtherMethod()` will be executed in case of any error.

Comment: Using .block in reactive scenarios is not a good idea.

Comment: @red please read my answer carefully. Two solutions are provided, The second is the reactive one. WebClient can also be used on imperative/blocking applications.

Comment: I see that you deleted the `.block` from the second example, now it looks better :)